# How to run a terminal program like FFMPEG from Xcode coco app using swift?

Tags: swift, terminal

I am working on making a Xcode app using swift.  I am trying to run FFMPEG when someone clicks on a button.  In terminal it would look like

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

But after searching everywhere, I can't seem to find how to run a command as if you were typing it into Terminal.

So my question is, how do you run a command (probably from a textfield) just as if you typed it into Terminal?

Here is my code so far:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var inURL: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var inText: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    @IBAction func clickURL(_ sender: Any) {
        var musicURL = inURL.stringValue
        if musicURL.isEmpty {
            musicURL = "No URL entered!"
        }
        let textReplace = "Downloading music from: \(musicURL)..."
        inText.stringValue = textReplace
        Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2/bin/ffmpeg", arguments: ["-i","input.mp4","output.mp4"])
    }
}
```

I will also be using youtube-dl from GitHub, if I can get FFMPEG working.

Comment: Look into the `Process` class.

Comment: Where is the best place to go for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/a/path/to/ffmpeg", arguments: ["-i", "input.mp4", "output.mp4"])
```

Comment: Well, this is tested. Check paths, use absolute ones first. Try launching another console app. Isn’t your app sandboxed? Can you see something in the output window in xcode?

Comment: Oh, am I getting this from console:  2019-04-15 11:34:17.289936-0500 Download Music[56325:14019595] [General] launch path not accessible

Comment: Why would it be "not accessible" if I can see it in finder from that path?

Comment: In the location "/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2/bin/ffmpeg" there are 2 files "ffmpeg" and "ffprobe".  They are both unix exec files.

Comment: I am new to swift and I really don't like it.

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the path? have you tried launching some other command line app? Have you tried to copy the ffmpg to another location (Desktop, etc) and launch it from there? Have you tried to launch the ffmpeg from terminal, using exactly the same path? ...

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to do this at the moment and it seems to be a permission issue, has nothing to do with swift. I recently read it [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/654579). The idea is that sandboxed apps cannot read files from just anywhere. For some standard paths, you can enable access (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW7)), but for others you cannot. Also, seems like it is possible to launch executables from `/usr/bin` by default, but not for `/usr/local/bin`, at least not without specifically enabling it. I'll be looking into this some more and come back if I find a proper solution.

**Edit:**
An option that I just tested an works for me, is to bundle `ffmpeg` in my app sandbox and use it from there. I downloaded `ffmpeg` from [here](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) and added it to Xcode in the target Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources, then accessed it programmatically from this path

```
let ffmpegPath = Bundle.main.bundlePath + "/Contents/Resources/ffmpeg"
```